# How can insert multiple records into temporary table from two date?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this query in my store procedure. The query is:

```
INSERT INTO #TeporaryTableAcquaMensile
SELECT 'WATER',CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE(),105),VALUE_START
FROM AA_V_MV_Obiettivi_x_modello_virtuale
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE(),105) between DatEStart and DateEnd
  and idtipoparametro=2 AND IDModelloVirtuale=15
```

This query works, but I want to insert the some value for every day from DateStart to DateEnd.

So, for example, if I have DateStart= 2015-12-01 and DateEnd = 2015-12-31, I want insert into my temporary table 31 records. It is possible to do this?

Comment: Which dbms? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: my database is T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You need to create a number table with data from 1 to 31 and use

```
create table numbers(number int)
insert into numbers(number)
select top 31 row_number() over (order by (select 1)) from master..spt_values

INSERT INTO #TeporaryTableAcquaMensile
    SELECT 'WATER',CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE(),105),VALUE_START
    FROM AA_V_MV_Obiettivi_x_modello_virtuale, numbers 
    WHERE CONVERT(varchar(12),GETDATE(),105) between DatEStart and DateEnd
      and idtipoparametro=2 AND IDModelloVirtuale=15 
and number between 1 and datediff(day,dateend,dateStart)
```